# How to get float in string?

Tags: python

Write a program, input a string , and put all the numeric strings in the string (except for the tail punctuation, it can be an integer or a float, for example, '100times', N0; '56.78.23' in the sentence, No; '45.78.' at the end of the sentence, Yes; or a single number) is converted to a floating point number and output. If there is no numeric string, output:‘Not Found!’ . The following punctuation marks may be included in the string: ",", ".", "", "?", and "!", punctuation does not appear consecutively.

Example:

```
string = " one 5.67 two 56.78.23 three 34 four 45.78. "
```

Result:

```
['5.67','45.78','34']
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you've written and what's not working?

Comment: Use a regexp to find all the numeric strings with `re.findall()`.

Comment: The problem description says that you're supposed to convert them to floating point numbers. Why does your desired result have strings in it?

Comment: Are you trying to find floats or numbers? Cause 34 is not a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do this is splitting the string, and trying to cast to float in a `try`/`except` clause:

```
def find_floats(string):
    for i in string.rstrip('. ').split():
        try:
            float(i)
            yield i
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

---

```
list(find_floats(string))
# ['5.67', '34', '45.78.']
```

Comment: Won't `float(2)` turn the `int` 2 into 2.0?

Comment: No, it is not being assigned anywhere... @daudnadeem

Comment: no I mean if I open up a python shell, and type `float("string")` I get a `ValueError`. However both `float(1)` and `float(1.0)` return `1.0`

Comment: Yes, so? OP is looking for numeric values @daudnadeem

Comment: yes, I noticed that. However the question is misleading since it states "float in sting" and not "numbers in string"

Comment: Yes, but OP does have a `24` in the output @daudnadeem so I guess it's clear enough what OP really does want. But sure, I see what u mean